# Stop extension of year dropdown in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker script in one of my project, the script url is:
[Script URL](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

I have set year range +100 years and -100 years from the current date. Now if user selects 2010 from year dropdown, script automatically refresh the year dropdown with selected value. Now new options are:

2010-100 and 2010+100

I dont need this functionality. Can I stop this beahaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

> The range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to today's year (`"-nn:+nn"`), relative to the currently selected year (`"c-nn:c+nn"`), absolute (`"nnnn:nnnn"`)

Are you setting relative to the currently selected year? Set relative to today's year instead.

(This answer could've been more precise and helpful if you were showing us any of the code you were using. Hope this helps anyway.)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I am using "c-nn:c+nn" format in year range. and dont want to use absolute values because the list is vary according to year. Is there anyway to do this with floating year range?

Comment: You can set it relative to today's year rather than to the currently selected year. Don't use absolute values; use `-100:+100` rather than `c-100:c+100`.